# Jquery Boxy textarea value

Tags: jquery, textarea, boxy

I've got a textarea called fou in my Boxy popup.
How do I get the value of the text once the user has clicked a Submit button in the popup?
I thought    $('textarea[id$=fou]').val()  wold do the trick but no.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fou').val();
```

or

```
$('textarea[id="fou"]').val();
```

Comment: that would be true if it was straight jquery, but the Boxy plugin throws things for a loop.

Comment: you pass all your html into the Boxy object and it renders the popup, how to get elements out is the trick part.

Comment: create a jsfiddle.net/ and I will take a look, unless you have a live version for me to see.